# How to turn off nvidia GPU after Nsight shutdown on linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

Everytime I start the CUDA IDE Nsight, the nvidia GPU turns on. When I close Nsight, the GPU stays on, making laptop hot.

Is there any configuration I can use to automatically turn it off when Nsight exit? I use bumblebee and bbswitch.

Comment: I would write a script that will start the program, then upon closing the program, the script continues and disables the GPU.

Comment: But I didn' t actually find a reliable way of turning GPU off. Such as restarting bumblebee, reloading bbswitch, etc. Do you know a reliable way to turn it off temporaly?

Comment: I assume the GPU was turned off, and by running Nsight, it was turned on.  Why can't you use the method that you used to turned the GPU off originally?

Comment: It is only turned off after reboot. Maybe Nsight loads some kernel module that prevent it from turning off. I will try rmmod some module later.